# Problem with JavaScript Worker - worker doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I have a Worker in Javascript

The problem is, it doesn't work :)
Here is my Worker code: 

*myWorker.js*

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(url) {
   console.log('worker starts work');
   var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlHttp.open("GET", url, false);
   xmlHttp.send();
   self.postMessage(xmlHttp.responseText);
});
```

*main.js*

```
function aFunction(){
    var worker = new Worker('myWorker.js');
    worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
        console.log('worker has done his work');
        // doing some things after worker finish work
     });
    worker.postMessage(url);
}
```

I should mention that both *main.js* and the *myWorker.js* are placed in the same folder 
The worker doesn't do any part of the code
Any mistakes?
I am not that fluent in JS

Comment: "a separate thread to get a HTTP request from server
I don't want to block the UI
" — You don't need a worker to do that. XMLHttpRequest (and it's modern replacement, fetch) are non-blocking by default. Just don't pass `false` as the third argument to `open` and use a `load` event listener to process the data.

Comment: `xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")` doesn't make sense. A GET request can't have content, so saying its content is JSON is nonsense.

Comment: let's add what from console

Comment: @Quentin , it sounds like a solution for the base of my problem, thanks, but I am also wondering why the Worker doesn't work :/

Comment: What you receive in the message event handler is a MessageEvent, not a string. You want to extract that data from its `.data` property.

Answer (score 0):

as @Kaiido said:
"What you receive in the message event handler is a MessageEvent, not a string. You want to extract that data from its `.data` property."

the correct code is:

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(url) {
   console.log('worker starts work');
   var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlHttp.open("GET", url.data, false);
   xmlHttp.send();
   self.postMessage(xmlHttp.responseText);
});
```